# Calling materialize css modal tru php edit

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Here I have code to show my table with edit button I am trying to call materialize css
modal when it is clicked on that button but nothing shows up not sure where should I call that script tried multiple methods

```
echo '<table class= "striped" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"> 
    <thead>
      <tr> 
          <td>ID</td> 
          <td>Ime</td> 
          <td>Prezime</td> 
          <td>OIB</td> 
          <td>Datum odlaska</td>
          <td></td>
      </tr></thead>';

      if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $evidencijaid = $row["evidencijaId"];
            $turistime = $row["evidencijaTuristIme"];
            $turistprezime = $row["evidencijaTuristPrezime"];
            $turistoib = $row["evidencijaTuristOIB"];
            $turistDatum = $row["evidencijaTuristDatumOdlaska"];
            echo '<tbody><tr> 
                      <td>'.$evidencijaid.'</td> 
                      <td>'.$turistime.'</td> 
                      <td>'.$turistprezime.'</td> 
                      <td>'.$turistoib.'</td> 
                      <td>'.$turistDatum.'</td> 
                      <td><a data-target="modal1" class= "waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/evidencija.php?edit='.$row['evidencijaId'].' "><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></a></td>
                      <td><a class= "waves-effect waves-light btn edit" href="http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/includes/evidencija.inc.php?delete='.$row['evidencijaId'].'"><span class="fas fa-trash"></span></a></td>
                  </tr>';
        }
        $result->free();
    }
```

Here is my code that should throw values into opened modal when edit button is clicked

```
if (isset($_GET["edit"])){
$id = $_GET['edit'];
$editrow = izmijeniEvidenciju($conn, $id);
echo '
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
<div class="row">
<form action="http://localhost/robinzonlucica/public/includes/evidencija.inc.php" class="col s12 registerforma" method="post">
<div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col s6">
         <input id="ime" type="text" class="validate" name="ime" value="'.$editrow['evidencijaTuristIme'].'">
         <label for="last_name">Ime Turista</label>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col s6">
         <input id="ime" type="text" class="validate" name="prezime" value="'.$editrow['evidencijaTuristPrezime'].'">
         <label for="last_name">Prezime turista</label>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col s6">
         <input id="ime" type="text" class="validate" name="oib" value="'.$editrow['evidencijaTuristOIB'].'">
         <label for="last_name">OIB Turista</label>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s6">
       <input type=text name="datum" id="datum" class="datepicker" value="'.$editrow['evidencijaTuristDatumOdlaska'].'">
       <label for="datum">Datum odlaska</label>
       </div>
       </div>
     <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light gumbsalji" type="submit" name="submit">Upiši</button>
   </div>
   </form>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
 </div>
</div>';
}
```

There is my opening script at the end in the body

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal-trigger').modal("open");
  });
</script>
```

Not sure where it went wrong even checked documentation not sure If I didn't get something right

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple rows in yours in table, each edit modal for every row needs to have a unique Id. You should use a FOR loop instead, this way u can echo out the ID for each modal like so (assuming your iterator is variable i) `id = modal<php echo i ?php>`. Then put this modal inside the FOR loop. And for your href on the edit button, it should be linking to the id of the modal u want to open like `href=#modal1` . And your `<tbody>` tags should be outside the echo, otherwise it will used every loop when you only need it once.